# MemoryError when using NetworkX simple_cycles() function

Tags: python, memory, out-of-memory, graph-algorithm, networkx

Documentation on `simple_cycles()` can be found here: http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html#id7

I have a directed graph with about 160,000 nodes and nearly 2,000,000 edges. Since the complexity of `simple_cycles()` is O((n+e)(c+1)), I thought it would be best to consider the strongly connected components independently. Luckily, are only 238 connected components. The largest component has 4,768 nodes and 31,157 edges. The next largest only has 6 nodes and 6 edges! So now my only problem is the subgraph with 4,768 nodes! However, using `simple_cycles()` on this subgraph still results in a `MemoryError`.

I am quite new to python (and programming in general), so I am unsure what's happening and what to try next.

I was first running this on a 32bit version of python, but I got `MemoryError`. For the past few days, I've been toying with a 64bit version of python, and it runs longer, but I still get a `MemoryError`. I was watching my memory allocation while it was running, and python would use up to 6gb then drop back down to near 0gb, to slowly build up to using 6gb again, and repeat. Several hours later, I get a `MemoryError`.

Perhaps there is a way to save its progress so it doesn't use so much memory. I'm assuming that this is what it is happening when python goes from using 6gb of memory to nearly 0gb - writing it to disk to get more access to memory? But, remember, I am new to this; I don't know what I am talking about. Any tips, recommendations, advice would be appreciated.

Comment: There are several algorithms to enumerate all cycles in a graph.  However this can take exponential time, as there can be exponentially many cycles in a graph, so you might be trying to solve an unsolvable problem.  Search should turn up descriptions of several algorithms for this problem.  I don't know why that particular library code is running out of memory, though.